# Object is possibly null inside a callback

Tags: typescript

I've got the following code:

```
             let ctx = ref.current.getContext("2d");
             if(ctx){
                ctx.lineWidth=1; // here is ok!
                ctx.strokeStyle=props.barStroke??"darkgray";// here is ok!
                ctx.fillStyle=props.barFill??"blue"; // here is ok!
                props.data.map((v,i)=>{
                    ctx.fillRect(i*10,0,10,props.height); //here it complain about ctx is possibly null!!
                    ctx.strokeRect(1*10,0,10,props.height);
                })

             }
```

I've checked ctx and so ctx.lineWidth works without errors, but inside the callback, it signals that the object could be possibly null. If I use `ctx?.method` code works anyway, so how can be ctx, checked for null outside the callback, became null inside it?
[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=34&pln=18&pc=35#code/MYGwhgzhAEBSCuEAuAxA9gJwCoAsCmAogB5gC2ADiHgN4BQ0D0waAdshvMEpgBQCU0atHqNRSHAEsIAOmDwMGPCyTQAvNBZ4A7tAASWALIAZAMJgWAN0gEqpJUn4BuEQwC%20LpvMXKAXHsOm5lYQNnh2ys7utFYY0IoAZmoa2nCIqJi4hCQUVM4SiTwJsl72AnSiFYwA9FU4SEjkED41yGDAANZoFngY8SBoWrJopFVgVQAsAJwAzJMADABsC1UArEsLcwAcHpUMNdBo4j1aUnjQJ%20LQ5gAm0PgSAOZ1B4lHTEGQV4rQ5If2EmAQCAAJ7Qa75eI9ezQeIYYbQN6sM4SFgI-DQZDAqg7XZxPDxYoKezSE7XcSqACMczmzlxFSKciJymk9yeSEp1NpdMYVBUXCISQZJWZDzwSBMrCQeCIDgARAAma6yvhc7nQfI8fl8cpq0T86QgFF4ADqEjJOEpqt1TCQRGk7DQ7TwAGUkFi8KpZQAjEDwPCyq26-XxCRA13uz3AvBAgYBnHcgDaFIANPLk9Nk%20NkytkwsALrSeKYAhtHA8HgWZMSPiqAB8OutFWDoZAACU8FweBIAFQUlNzZNUwfUvjx636h1O9udnt95MDodUuYqse41yjxsMVeidxroA) a link showing the problem.

Comment: (side note - only use `.map` to construct a new array. For side effects, use `forEach` or `for..of`)

Comment: Do you mean `callback` for inside `props.data.map((v,i)=>{`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10982):

This is working as intended. The type checker knows that `ctx` is non-null at the time the callback function is created, but it doesn't know that `ctx` is non-null when the callback is called (because bar is a mutable property that could be changed before or between calls to the callback function).

The suggested way to do this is to copy `ctx` into a const local and then use that in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
      let ctx = ref.current.getContext("2d");
         if(ctx) {
            ctx.lineWidth=1; // here is ok!
            ctx.strokeStyle=props.barStroke??"darkgray";// here is ok!
            ctx.fillStyle=props.barFill??"blue"; // here is ok!
            props.data.map((v,i)=>{
                ctx.fillRect(i*10,0,10, v.height); //here it complain about ctx is possibly null!!
                ctx.strokeRect(1*10,0,10, v.height);
            })

         }
```

Looks like `props` is't predicted not ctx. Because ctx is refered like local variable already.

Answer (score 0):

See Matthieu Riegler's answer for a description of *why* this is happening. Another solution is to use a `for` loop instead of a callback, since the callback (which TS isn't smart enough to determine is occurring exactly when it's being declared in the `.map` callback) is what's causing the issue:

```
let ctx = document.querySelector<HTMLCanvasElement>('foo')!.getContext("2d");
if (ctx) {
    const props = {
        data: ['x', 'y'],
        height: 10
    }
    for (const [i, v] of props.data.entries()) {
        ctx.fillRect(i * 10, 0, 10, props.height);
        ctx.strokeRect(1 * 10, 0, 10, props.height);
    }
}
```